# Python Tkinter menubar

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is some sample code, everything works as far as the menu, and the gui for the function, but the function doesn't work when you pass values it, when what I want it to do is calculate the problem, as it is designed to.

i want the function to be a separate program, to the main window, as it is.
The reason is I want to add more of these mathematical functions to a menu.

How can I get this function to work? I am new, go easy please....
Thank you in advance...

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk


def DVT():
    def dvt(*args):
        """This Function will determine distance in feet from a constant velocity and time"""
        try:
            val1 = float(vel.get())
            val2 = float(tme.get())
            dist.set(val1 * val2)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    root = Tk()
    root.title('Distance from Velocity and Time')

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    vel = StringVar()
    tme = StringVar()
    dist = StringVar()

    vel_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=vel)
    vel_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
    tme_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=tme)
    tme_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(E, W))

    ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=dist).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=dvt).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Velocity").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Time").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="The Distance is:").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E) 

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    vel_entry.focus()
    tme_entry.focus()
    root.bind('<Return>', dvt) 
    root.mainloop()


root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)


vel = StringVar()
tme = StringVar()
dist = StringVar()


filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Distance from Velocity and Time", command=DVT)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)


editmenu.add_separator()

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox

def DVT():

    vel = StringVar()
    tme = StringVar()
    dist = StringVar()

    def dvt():
        """This Function will determine distance in feet from a constant velocity and time"""
        try:
            val1 = float(vel_entry.get())
            val2 = float(tme_entry.get())
            dist.set(val1 * val2)
            tkMessageBox.showinfo(None,"The Distance is: " + dist.get())
        except ValueError as v:
            pass


    root = Tk()
    root.title('Distance from Velocity and Time')

    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


    vel_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7)
    vel_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(E, W))
    tme_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7)
    tme_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(E, W))


    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=dvt).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Velocity").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Time").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="The Distance is:").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E)

    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

    vel_entry.focus()
    tme_entry.focus()
    root.bind('<Return>', dvt) 
    root.mainloop()

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Distance from Velocity and Time", command=DVT)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)


editmenu.add_separator()

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you edit this answer to explain the code and why it applies?

Comment: @tjrob if this answer was helpful, you may consider "accept it" (tick the cross to turn it green). See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation